# Windows XP doesn't boot after upgrading Ubuntu partition to 10.04

Tags: windows-xp, boot, ubuntu-10.04, grub

I have Windows XP and Ubuntu on dual boot - loaded with grub.
It worked fine until I upgraded Ubuntu to 10.04 and now when I select Windows XP at the grub screen, it goes black for a few seconds, then returns to grub. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer. [This guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems:Boot_Sector) worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create/modify /etc/grub.d/11_Windows to boot WinXP...

```
#! /bin/sh -e  
echo "Adding Windows XP" >&2  
cat << EOF  
menuentry "Windows XP" {  
insmod ntfs  
set root=(hd1,1)  
drivemap -s (hd0) \${root}  
chainloader +1  
}  
EOF
```

Then of course run update-grub and reboot...

Dell Optiplex GX520
2GB Ram
500GB Sata - Ubuntu 9.10 (/dev/sda)
250GB Sata - WinXP Professional (/dev/sdb)

Found that os-prober and thus 30_os-prober were NOT working so WinXP was not detected. Still researching why os-prober isn't detecting WinXP. I have three other systems, Debian 5 (64bit)/Win7 Ultimate (ASUS P6T), Ubuntu 10.04/WinXP (EPOX EP-4PLMI) and Ubuntu 9.10/WinXP (HP Pavilion dv8000 laptop) and on these os-prober/30_os-prober work fine.

Hope this helps some...